# Cycles and Closed Paths

Tags: homological-algebra, triangulation

$\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$

> Show that if $\Delta$ is a triangulation, then $[a_1, b_1]+[a_2, b_2]+\cdots+[a_n,b_n]$ is a $1$-cycle precisely when the indicated oriented edges $1$-faces form a closed path.
>
> This is what I have in my notes:
>
> Out of a triangulation, we get a sequence $$0 \stackrel{\partial_0}\longleftarrow C_0 \stackrel{\partial_1}\longleftarrow C_1 \stackrel{\partial_2}\longleftarrow \cdots \longleftarrow C_n \stackrel{\partial_n}\longleftarrow \cdots$$
>
> with $Z_n = \ker \partial_n \supseteq B_n = \Im (\partial_{n+1})$

If the oriented $1$-faces form a closed path, then they must be a boundary of the $2$-faces, but the boundary operator applied to $B_1$ is zero, since $\ker \partial_n \supseteq B_n = \Im (\partial_{n+1})$. So $\Im(\partial_2) = B_1  \subseteq \ker \partial_1$.

For the converse, we have: $1$-cycle $\implies$ boundary is zero $\implies$ is contained in the kernel of $\partial_1$. So now I have to prove that it is also contained in the image of $\partial_2$. Now I'm a bit confused, because the image of $[a,b,c]$ is $[a,b]-[a,c]+[b,c]$ ... so if a $1$-cycle is of that form, then it definitely is an image of a $2$-face. But we can have all kinds of $1$-cycles, right? For example $[a,b]+[b,a]$ is also a $1$-cycle and I can't really see how that would be a boundary of a $2$-face, since it is not of the form $[a,b]-[a,c]+[a,c]$.

Also, is there a formal definition of a "closed path"? I know what it means intuitively, because our professor showed it using a diagram, but I'm not sure if there is a formal definition, of if it's meant to only have an intuitive definition. I tried to google it but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: A closed path in $X$ is a function $f\colon[0,1]\rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$.

Comment: more specifically, here closed path means that you can reorder so that $a_{k+1}=b_k$, $a_1=b_n$.

Comment: I think you are confusing "closed path" and "boundary", aren't you? And you're trying to prove something which is not true, that is: that every $1$-cycle is a boundary.

Comment: I think you have confused cycles and boundaries.  A cycle is any sum of chains whose boundary cancels identically.  A boundary is any boundary of a sum of chains.  The basic fact is that every boundary is a cycle, but the converse is far from true.  Indeed, quantifying failure of the converse to hold — i.e. counting the number of cycles that are not boundaries — is exactly the point of homology, and provides topological information about the triangulation.

Comment: @DanielRust Is it wrong to say "If the oriented 1-faces form a closed path, then they must be a boundary of the 2-faces"? I can't see why it would be wrong, because it goes around a 2-face or a 2-chain, right?

Comment: @artus Suppose you have a triangulation of a cylinder, one of the boundary circles is a closed path but bounds no chain of $2$-faces.

Comment: @DanielRust We didn't really take the traingulation of a cylinder or anything similar to that. We only learned about the basic definition of a triangulation...that it was a triangular object in some space $R^n$. But there is something that makes me feel uncomfortable. If, as user8268 says, a closed path means that you can reorder so that $a_{k+1} = b_k, a_1 = b_n$, then applying the boundary operator to it *will* give us zero, right? What else could it possibly give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be mixing up the definitions of the various terms (chains, cycles, boundaries).

If $u$ is an $n$-chain and $\partial u=0$ we call $u$ a *cycle*. If there exists an $(n+1)$-chain $u'$ such that $\partial u'=u$ then we call $u$ a *boundary*. In homological algebra, we're particularly interested in the $n$-chains which are cycles but **not** boundaries, because such chains generate the $n$th homology group.

Let's go through an example. Let $\mathcal{K}$ be a simplicial complex with

- $0$-simplices $\{a,b,c,d\}$,
- $1$-simplices $\{[a,b],[b,c],[c,a],[a,d],[d,c]\}$, and
- $2$-simplicex $\{F=[a,b,c]\}$.

Draw a picture of this simplicial complex.

Now, let's find a couple of $1$-cycles in $\mathcal{K}$. It's easy enough to see that $\partial_1 ([a,b]+[b,c]+[c,a])=\partial_1(u_1)=0$ and also $\partial([c,a]+[a,d]+[d,c])=\partial(u_2)=0$ and so both $u_1$ and $u_2$ are cycles.

Now, we can also see that $\partial_2 (F)=u_1$ and so $u_1$ is also a boundary, as well as a cycle. Seeing as $C_2$ is generated by a single element (namely $F$), the image of a $2$-chain under $\partial_2$ will always be a linear combination of $u_1$. It follows that $u_2$ is not in the image of $\partial_2$ as $u_2$ can not be written as a multiple of $u_1$ and so $u_2$ is **not** a boundary, even though it is a cycle. This is pretty clear from the image you draw because it does not bound any $2$-simplex.

Given this example, I think you might be a bit better equipped to answer the question.